# How to find the images under anchor tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <a id="a1" href="javascript:DisplayURL();">
    <img src="image1.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function DisplayURL(){
     if ($('#mydiv').find('#a1').has("img"))
                {
                    alert($('a#a1 img').has("img").attr('src'));
                }
    }
```

I am getting undefined in alert?

Answer (score 1):

Points

1. .has() returns a jQuery wrapper, so you need to test the length of the returned object
2. since the `a` element has an `id` the selector `$('#mydiv').find('#a1')` can be reduced to `$('#a1')`
3. `$('#a1 img')` selects the `img` inside `a1` so there is no need to use .find()

It should be

```
function DisplayURL() {
    if ($('#a1').has("img").length) {
        alert($('#a1 img').attr('src'));
    }
}
```

it can be further changed as

```
function DisplayURL() {
    var $imgs = $('#a1 img');
    if ($imgs.length) {
        alert($imgs.attr('src'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
function DisplayURL() {
    if ($('#mydiv #a1').has("img").length) {
        alert($('#mydiv #a1').find("img").attr('src'));
    }
}
```